# Auto Python to EXE having issues with vispy glfw backend

Tags: python, python-3.x, glfw, auto-py-to-exe, vispy

I'm trying to convert a little game I used making p5.py but when I convert to .exe and try to open it always gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "minesweeper.py", line 499, in <module>
  File "p5\sketch\userspace.py", line 187, in run
  File "vispy\util\wrappers.py", line 93, in use
  File "vispy\app\_default_app.py", line 47, in use_app
  File "vispy\app\application.py", line 47, in __init__
  File "vispy\app\application.py", line 240, in _use
RuntimeError: Could not import backend "Glfw":
Could not import glwf, you may need to `pip install glfw` first.
```

I have gflw and vispy installed and the program runs normally when in the interpreter

Already tried to put vispy, glfw and vispy.app.backends._glfw on the hiden import section of auto-py-to-exe

Comment: I've never used auto-py-to-exe, but have used pyinstaller in the past. Specifying the glfw (or in my case pyqt) hidden import was always enough. Could you add some verbosity or debug flags to the build command and see if it mentions glfw anywhere?

Comment: Oh it could also be that some part of glfw is missing and the import is failing in some other way. There are `except` sections for `ImportError` or `Exception`, but a lot of errors fall under the `ImportError` umbrella (https://github.com/vispy/vispy/blob/5b4731cc6ca76d55041d4e7a0ba598d06525e5ac/vispy/app/backends/_glfw.py#L27-L32). You could try doing a `import glfw` in your `minesweeper.py` and see what the error is.